# NSURLSession send parameters with get

Tags: json, parsing, dictionary, swift

I'm trying to parse information from a php, but i need to send a dictionary parameter so i try things ... i saw tutorials,examples but i'm stuck so i went back to the start: (What it's the good way for do this?)

```
       func asd(){
    let urlPath = "http://xxxxx.php"

    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    var parm = ["id_xxxx": "900"] as Dictionary


    //I THINK MY PROBLEM IT'S HERE! i dont know how to link parm with session, i try is with session.uploadTaskWithRequest(<#request: NSURLRequest?#>, fromData: <#NSData?#>) but doesn't work

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        println("Task completed")
        if(error) {
            // If there is an error in the web request, print it to the console
            println(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        var err: NSError?
        var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as NSDictionary
        if(err?) {
            // If there is an error parsing JSON, print it to the console
            println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
        }
        println(jsonResult.debugDescription)
        let results: NSArray = jsonResult["x"] as NSArray
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.tableData = results
            self.OfertaGridViewLista!.reloadData()
            })
        })
    task.resume()
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Data is not sent with GET, all data needs to be in the URL query string. Take sone time to study http, GET and POST and URLs at a minimum.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

GET data needs to be part of the url's query string. Some methods will accept a dictionary of parameters for POST/PUT requests, but these methods will not add the dictionary to the url for you if you're using the GET method.

If you'd like to keep your GET parameters in a Dictionary for cleanliness or consistency, consider adding a method like the following to your project:

```
func buildQueryString(fromDictionary parameters: [String:String]) -> String {
    var urlVars:[String] = []
    
    for (k, value) in parameters {
        let value = value as NSString
        if let encodedValue = value.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: NSCharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed) {
            urlVars.append(k + "=" + encodedValue)
        }
    }

    return urlVars.isEmpty ? "" : "?" + urlVars.joined(separator: "&")
}
```

This method will take a dictionary of key/value pairs and return a string you can append to your url.

For example, if your API requests allow for multiple request methods (GET/POST/etc.) you'll only want to append this query string to your base api url for GET requests:

```
if (request.HTTPMethod == "GET") {
    urlPath += buildQueryString(fromDictionary: parm)
}
```

If you're only making GET requests, there's no need to check for which method you'll be using to send your data.

Comment: Xcode 7 requires replacing `join("&", urlVars)` with `urlVars.joinWithSeparator("&")`. See more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31069230/cannot-invoke-join-with-an-argument-list-of-type-string-string-in-swift-2

Comment: For Swift 3 use: `value.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)` and `urlVars.joined(separator: "&")`

Comment: The answer below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45125708/127853) by @alanzeino is a better option.

Answer (score 9):

Bit crazy that none of the answers here suggest using `NSURLComponents` and `NSURLQueryItem` objects. That is the safest and most modern way to do this.

```
var iTunesSearchURL = URLComponents(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/search")!
iTunesSearchURL.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "term", value: trackName),
                              URLQueryItem(name: "entity", value: "song"),
                              URLQueryItem(name: "limit", value: "1")]

let finalURL = iTunesSearchURL.url
```

Answer (score 4):

@paul-mengelt's answer in Objective C:

```
-(NSString *) buildQueryStringFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)parameters {
    NSString *urlVars = nil;
    for (NSString *key in parameters) {
        NSString *value = parameters[key];
        value = [value stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];
        urlVars = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@=%@", urlVars ? @"&": @"", key, value];
    }
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", urlVars ? @"?" : @"", urlVars ? urlVars : @""];
}
```

Comment: this code is not working, only the last <key:value> pair is returned

Comment: This is broken and untested, to prevent wasting anyones time, this answer should be removed or voted down.

Answer (score 2):

**Adapted for Swift 3**

```
  static func buildQueryString(fromDictionary parameters: [String:String]) -> String {
    var urlVars:[String] = []

    for (k,value) in parameters {
        if let encodedValue = value.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed) {
            urlVars.append(k + "=" + encodedValue)
        }
    }

    return urlVars.isEmpty ? "" : "?" + urlVars.joined(separator: "&")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

fixed objective C function

```
+(NSString *)buildQueryStringFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)parameters
{
    NSString *urlVars = @"";
    for (NSString *key in parameters)
    {
        NSString *value = parameters[key];
        value = [value stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLHostAllowedCharacterSet]];
        urlVars = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@=%@", urlVars, urlVars.length ? @"&": @"", key, value];
    }
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", urlVars ? @"?" : @"", urlVars ? urlVars : @""];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"url_to_your_web_service.php/?key=%@",value]];

NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject];
NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask = [defaultSession dataTaskWithURL:url
                                                completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                    if(error == nil){
                                                        NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                                        NSLog(@"Data = %@",text);
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                   ];
[dataTask resume];
```

retrieve key's value inside your php:

$value=$_GET['key'];