# Cannot invoke `join` with an argument list of type (String, [String]) in Swift 2.0

Tags: swift, swift2

```
var specializationTitles = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
let outputString = join(" / ", specializationTitles)
```

got an error:

> Cannot invoke `join` with an argument list of type `(String, [String])`

How to solve this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
let separator = " / "
let outputString = separator.join(specializationTitles)
```

With Xcode7beta6:

```
specializationTitles.joinWithString(" / ")
```

With Xcode7 release version:

```
specializationTitles.joinWithSeparator(" / ")
```

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 2.0 ( which is default on Xcode 7), you will have to use, `joinWithSeparator`

```
specializationTitles.joinWithSeparator(" / ")
```