# Getting number from String Swift 2 Issue

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, nsnumber, nsnumberformatter

I was able to get the phone number from the textfield with the method below in Swift 1.2 but I'm trying the same method in Swift 2 but I'm getting an error from `.join` "join is unavailable". Please how can I write the same method in Swift 2?

```
let userNumber = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString("".join(phoneNumberTextField.text!.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet)))
```

This answer didn't help me that I can't get join at all.
[Cannot invoke `join` with an argument list of type (String, [String]) in Swift 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31069230/cannot-invoke-join-with-an-argument-list-of-type-string-string-in-swift-2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot invoke \`join\` with an argument list of type (String, \[String\]) in Swift 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31069230/cannot-invoke-join-with-an-argument-list-of-type-string-string-in-swift-2)

Comment: @EricD. I couldn't get join at all when I start typing join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
let numbers = phoneNumberTextField.text!.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet)
let userNumber = numbers.joinWithSeparator(" ") // Using space as separator
```