# How to retrieve Google Search Results in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, search, google-search

I set up a Custom Google Search per this post: [What are the alternatives now that the Google web search API has been deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082966/what-are-the-alternatives-now-that-the-google-web-search-api-has-been-deprecated).

Now I need to implement it in my app, and I want to fire off a request to search my custom search and I need to work with the results I get back (the JSON I believe).

I would imagine I need to use `NSURLSession` to make the request, but I can't quite figure out the proper syntax.

This is the custom search's URL: `https://cse.google.com/cse/publicurl?cx=XXXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXX`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify this to fit your needs:

```
googleUrl = "https://cse.google.com/cse/publicurl?cx=XXXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXX"
guard url = NSURL(string: googleUrl) else { return }
NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) {
    (data, response, error) in
    // deal with error etc accordingly       
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I do also need to add `/search?q=someString` to the request but can't figure out the syntax

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25223399/nsurlsession-send-parameters-with-get

Comment: is there anyway that i can get current phone image from google